# Cloned Parse server shares data

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, parse-server

My app has been using single Parse server for a while now, everything is fine.
After some time, one of the developers asked me to clone this Parse server, so he can experiment with it.

So I've cloned the whole completely and started new Parse server on a different IP (for example, `10.10.10.10:4040` and `20.20.20.20:4040`). Parse started, I've accessed Parse Dashboard, everything was ok.

But then I noticed that changes that I do in a testing Parse server, also appear in a main Parse server (even though they are on different IP's).

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that by 'changes you do', you mean data and not code. Both of your parse instances seem to be connecting to the same MongoDB database.

If you want you could clone the MongoDB collections to another database. Or better yet use another instance and separate your main db from this experimental one.